# Ошибка при открытии MVC сайта без указания action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Есть шаблонный проект MVC 5.0, созданный в VS 2013. После публикации сайта на сервере IIS 8.5 не открывается страница http://localhost:85/Home/

**Ошибка**: This page can’t be displayed

Есть попробовать открыть http://localhost:85/Home/Index то все нормально открывается. Проблема не воспроизводится на IIS 7.0

Роутинг по умолчанию не менял. Добавил новый контроллер SignInController и View/SignIn/Index.cshtml - ситуация аналогичная: если в url указывать index, то страница открывается.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Максимум, что нагуглил: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411457/iis-8-5-mvc-5-routes-api-controllername-gives-404-not-found-error)

Шаблонный код контроллера HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Copy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Шаблонный код роутинга:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

Comment: а на IIS 8.5 установлен asp.net?

Comment: а где код роутов, где код контроллеров?

Comment: @Grundy да. На сервере крутятся несколько сайтов (web forms). Страницы MVC проекта работают, если указывать название метода на конце.

Comment: @Dmitry исправил. Проект сделан из встроенного шаблона.

Comment: @rogueCapella, попробуйте обратится без указания контроллера в том числе.

Comment: @Dmitry без указания контролера - открывает страницу. Почему - не знаю.

Comment: @rogueCapella потому что контроллер `Home` и действие `Index` указаны по умолчанию, при указании контроллера так же требуется указывать и действие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Частное решение**:

Проблема скрывалась в установленном на сервере **ISAPI_Rewrite** от Helicon, который подменял стандартный MVC модуль.
Обнаружить данным модуль можно в настойках сайта - Фильтры ISAPI.

По данному вопросу я также нашел следующие решения:

1. [Статья](http://devproconnections.com/development/aspnet-why-iis-turns-developers-love-story-hate) Проверьте, что **IUSR** имеет права на папку, в которой опубликован проект. В **IIS 8** учетная запись IUSR используется для анонимного доступа. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279593/401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials/28836927#28836927)
2. Обходной вариант, который я задействовал, прежде чем нашел правильное решение [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411457/iis-8-5-mvc-5-routes-api-controllername-gives-404-not-found-error)
3. Убедиться, что на сервере включена роль ASP.NET 4.5. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025455/mvc-4-website-with-net-4-5-on-iis-8-in-windows-8-gives-403-14-forbidden-error)

Answer (score 0):

Если в шаблоне роута есть указание на контроллер и действие, то необходимо указывать оба свойства шаблона. Если указан так же и дефолтный шаблон и дефолтное действие, то для обращения к действию не требует указания контроллера ровно как и действия.

например:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

вызов может выглядеть так:

```
/Home/Index    
/
// Если действие принимает параметр Id то можно и его передать
/Home/Index/3
/3
```

Или к примеру такой роут

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

вызов может выглядеть так:

```
/Home/Index
/Home
// Если действие принимает параметр Id то можно и его передать
/Home/Index/3
/Home/3
```